# Доступ к файлу из файла по гиперссылке в андроид

Tags: android

Имеются 5-ть локальных текстовых файлов которые открываются в WebView.
В тексте первого документа хочу разместить ссылки на остальные файлы для возможности запуска новых файлов.
Файлы для просмотра в WebView располагаются в папке raw.
Как мне указать ссылку для такого подхода.

Answer (score 1):

Перенёс файлы из папки `res/raw` в папку `assets` и сменил расширение от `txt` на `html` и всё заработало.

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/n0.html">
```